# React Native IOS Image Not Updating

Tags: react-native-ios

I have an Image Component that needs to be updated periodically after state change. The app works perfectly on Android but the images do not load on IOS. Also the links are in https and work perfectly on IOS normally, but after uri state change, the image area is blank. Also after the OnloadStart event, the onLoad event does not fire on IOS.

## Image Component

```
 <Image
        source={{uri: this.state.uploadUrl}} 
        style = {{resizeMode:'stretch',width:'auto',height:125,marginTop:50,marginBottom:15}}

     onLoad={() => {
      alert('loaded image! ')
    }}
    onLoadStart={() => {
      alert('load starting: ' + this.state.uploadUrl)
  }}
/>
```

## State Change

```
 this.setState({isTrying:false,uploadUrl: responseJson.data.uploadUrl,adUrl : responseJson.data.adUrl});
```